# Dhtmlx tree api undefined

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx

I am trying to use some api http://docs.dhtmlx.com/api__dhtmlxtree_saveselecteditem.html to save the state of a tree in my project but every time is undefined :

```
undefined is not a function
```

This is the code:

```
tree_1.setImagePath('./codebase/thirdparty/dhtmlxtree/imgs/dhxtree_'+"skyblue"+'/');
tree_1.enableItemEditor(1);
tree_1.enableCheckBoxes(1);
tree_1.enableThreeStateCheckboxes(true);


tree_1.saveSelectedItem("ww");// undefined is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a "PRO" method. If you haven't it - this method will not work